# crystal reports project deployment

Tags: deployment, crystal-reports

I'm trying to deploy my crystal reports windows application project on clients computer.
the problem is I can't to load reports.
I installed CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_1 on client computer to solve the problem
but I encounter another error which appears when I try to load any of reports, the error is :
unhandled exception has occurred in your application, if you click continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. if you click quit, the application will close immediately,
when I click Continue button, my report loads without any data loaded.
what is the solution? the error detail is :
See the end of this message for details on invoking
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the path to the data source is incorrect I would recommend ensuring that the path not only exists but has the right permissions.

Comment: my data source is an object which previously filled from database. using this object I fill datatables of my dataset for reporting actions. can you explain how should check pathes and permissions?

Comment: just check that you have read permissions set for the correct user on the data source and that the path in the report to the datat source matches the physical path. It would also be prudent to check that the object interface fits what the report expects exactly and is returning values that fit into the schema as that could really screw you up

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot, 
I used manual addressing in assigning report file for my reportDocument.load() method
when program loads on client computer, address goes invalid.

the problem solved!

instad of using reportDocument and manual addressing I make new object from each report file (which haves .cs class) and assing it to crystalreportwiewer.reportsource:

```
Rad.ExecuteForms.Forms.Reports.CrystalReport1 noticeMainReport = new Reports.CrystalReport1();
        noticeMainReport.SetDataSource(Main);
        noticeMainReport.VerifyDatabase();
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = noticeMainReport;
```